# Starting a Activity in a Fragment with several Buttons

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I am still relatively new in programming with Java and I would like to open a fragment with several buttons different activities. However, I always get an error (... is already defined in ...) at the following location:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Also in other variants it did not work and there were even more errors.

Here is the full code of my Fragment:

```
public DashboardFragment() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stundenplanbtn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Stundenplan.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

    ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vertretungsbtn);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Vertretungsplan.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

    ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.essenbtn);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Essen.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you actually want is this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stundenplanbtn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Stundenplan.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vertretungsbtn);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Vertretungsplan.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

    return rootView;

}
```

Also, in the `Android` specific context you don't really all the ImageButton casting etc. since you're not using any specific method of the `ImageButton` class and since it `extends` the `View` class you can simply use:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);


    rootView.findViewById(R.id.stundenplanbtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Stundenplan.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

    rootView.findViewById(R.id.vertretungsbtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Vertretungsplan.class);
                    startActivity(intent);


                }
            });

 return rootView;

}
```

Note the **only** thing here is not creating the `button`variables/references, so it's just a small improvement. But if this is confusing you at the moment just ignore and use the first one.